# Why doesn't the Price.php calculate final price correctly?

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I try to get the final price of a simple product in a Plugin. The regular price of the product is 12.99 but it is affected by a catalog price rule of 50%.
Everything works fine in the frontend. There it's displayed with the 6.50, but when I try to use it in a Plugin, I always get the regular price.

I use the vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Type/Price::getFinalPrice($qty, $product) method:

```
private function getFinalPriceForMyPlugin(array $product): float 
{
   /** @var Product $productEntity */
   $productEntity = $this->productRepository->get((string)$product['sku']);
   return (float) $this->price->getFinalPrice(1, $productEntity);
}
```

I was pretty sure the Price.php was responsible for calculating the final price. So why doesn't it work?

Btw cache was flushed and the indexer was reindexed

Answer (score 0):

You can get Regular price and Final price of all types of products using the below way.

1. Simple Product

   ```
   $regularPrice = $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('regular_price')->getValue(); $specialPrice = $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('special_price')->getValue();
   ```
2. Configurable Product

   ```
   if ($product->getTypeId() == 'configurable') {
       $basePrice = $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('regular_price');

       $regularPrice = $basePrice->getMinRegularAmount()->getValue();
       $specialPrice = $product->getFinalPrice();
   }
   ```

Comment: I tried this but that doesnt work. I always get 0 as a result. The reason is the getValue() Method in Pricing/Price/SpecialPrice.php. The condition $this->isScopeDateInInterval() returns false because (I think) the valid time scope for the special price is off the limits.

Comment: But I think the special price is not even the one I need. I am looking for the final price. The final price is the lowest price of regular_price, catalog_rule_price, special_price and tier_price.

Comment: For instance, I have products which are affected by a catalog price rule. Neither regular price, nor special price are giving me the correct value.

You can find the difference in here: [Final Price](https://bsscommerce.com/confluence/magento-2-pricing/#7-final-price)

But I still have no idea how to get the final price